# How to work out External Data source and Object

Tags: lightning-connect

Can anyone tell me how to create external data source and object?
My requirement is :
I have an Excel sheet which has some information about mobiles(Table name Mobile)
I wanna make an external data object(which has information about mobiles ) from that excel
For That how Can I do?
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 0):

The data you access has to be accessible from Salesforce. You need to put that Excel sheet somewhere, such as Microsoft Office 365 or Google Sheets.  Then you would need to write or buy a Lightning Connect custom adapter that knows how to talk to the API of the cloud provider on which you are hosting that Excel data.